# My Ionic app throws a "has no method 'startInit'" error when using OneSignal

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

In my Ionic smart phone app, I'm using OneSignal to handle push notifications.  According to some OneSignal docs, I need to initialize their plugin like this:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.init(
    "b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba", 
    {googleProjectNumber: "703322744261"}, 
    notificationOpenedCallback
);
```

This works for me.  But other documentation says I should do this:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("YOUR_APPID", "YOUR_GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER_IF_ANDROID")
    .handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
        alert("Notification received:\n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        console.log('Did I receive a notification: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    })
    .endInit();
```

This is what I would prefer to do, since I really want that "handleNotificationReceived" option, not just the "notificationOpenedCallback" option.  But it's not working for me.  I get a Javascript error saying the method "startInit" doesn't exist in the "window.plugins.OneSignal" object.  It's right.  There is no method "startInit", so how can I use the code that calls it?

So what am I doing wrong?  Am I not using the latest version of OneSignal?  I just ran "ionic plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin --save", so I should be using their latest version.  (It installs version ~1.13.2, according to my config.xml).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer 2.+ version of the SDK is not out yet. You should refer to the old docs for this [here](https://documentation-old.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-installation)

**EDIT**

The new version of the SDK is now out and you can get it [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/releases/tag/2.0.4). Also new docs are [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup).

Answer (score 0):

Was getting the same issue. You could try reinstalling the plugins or add the platform again android/ios. That worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, reinstalling worked for you because by now they actually released version 2.